# Make array from multiple dynamic input textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get 3 different array readouts of the values added after I click on submit, can someone please help me. I would like it to look something like this...

**balance_array = 1,2,3,4,5,6 and so on...**

**loan_array = 1,2,3,4,5,6 and so on...**

**rate_array = 1,2,3,4,5,6 and so on...**

***I guess the real question is how do I get the value of balance0,balance1 and so on.. and add it to an array and then I can repeat that for the others also.***

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style type="text/css">
    body {
    .entry:not(:first-of-type) {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .glyphicon {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
var counter = 1;
$(function() {
    //console.log($('#template_add_form'));
    var clone = function(tmpl) {
            return $((tmpl.clone()).html())
        },
        $template = $('#template_add_form'),
        formArray = [ clone($template) ], // init array with first row
        $formEntries = $('#entries');

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function() {
        //console.log('clicked');
        formArray.push(clone($template));
        updateForm();
                            counter++;
        // set focus to adding row = last element in array
        $(formArray).last()[0]
            .find('input')
            .first()
            .focus();
    });

    // remove not working yet

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(evt) {
        var id;
        // iterate over formArray to find the currently clicked row
                            counter--;
        $.each(formArray, function(index, row) {
            //console.log(index, row.has(evt.currentTarget).length);
            if ( row.has(evt.currentTarget).length == 1 ) {
                //console.log(row.has(evt.currentTarget));
                id = index; // click target in current row
                return false; // exit each loop
            }

        });

        //console.log('clicked', id);
        formArray.splice(id, 1);
        updateForm();

    });

    var updateForm = function() {
        // redraw form --> problem values are cleared!!
        // console.log(formArray);
        var lastIndex = formArray.length - 1,
            name; // stores current name of input

        $formEntries.empty(); // clear entries from DOM becaue we re-create them
        $.each(formArray, function(index, $input) {
            //console.log(index, $input);
            // update names of inputs and add index
            //console.log('inputs', $input.find('input'));
            $.each($input.find('input'), function(inputIndex, input) {
                name = $(input).attr('name').replace(/\d+/g, ''); // remove ids
                $(input).attr('name', name + index);
            });

            if (index < lastIndex) {
                // not last element --> change button to minus
                //console.log($input.find('.btn-add'));
                $input.find('.btn-add')
                     .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
                     .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
                     .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
            }

            $formEntries.append($input);
$('#counter').val(counter);
        });
    };

    updateForm(); // first init. of form

});
//]]> 

</script>

<form id="loanform" action="#" role="form" autocomplete="off" method="post">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="action" value="cancel">
<script id="template_add_form" type="text/template">
    <div class = "entry input-group col-xs-9">
        <div class = "col-xs-3">
            <input class = "form-control" name="balance" type = "text" 
                   placeholder = "Loan Balance" required = "required"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input class="form-control" name="rate" type="text" placeholder="Interest Rate" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input class="form-control" name="payment" type="text" placeholder="Minimum Payment" required="required"/>
        </div> 
        <span class="input-group-btn col-xs-1">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span >
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="control-group" id="fields">
            <label class="control-label" for="field1">
                 <h3>Enter your loans below</h3>

            </label>
            <div class="controls">
                    <div class="entry input-group col-xs-3">How much extra money can you pay per month?
                        <input class="form-control" name="extra" type="text" placeholder="Extra/month">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div id="entries"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br> <small>Press <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus gs"></span> to add another loan</small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

THANKS SO MUCH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array values can be captured by naming the div's with appropriate class for example:

```
<input class="form-control rate" name="rate" type="text" placeholder="Interest Rate" required="required" />
```

And then reading the values by classname on submit event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#submit').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var balanceArray = [];
         var rateArray = [];
         var paymentArray = []  
         $('.balance').each(function(item){
            balanceArray.push($(this).val());  
         });
         $('.rate').each(function(item){
            rateArray.push($(this).val());  
         });
         $('.payment').each(function(item){
            paymentArray.push($(this).val());  
         });
    });
});
```